# Fun with generics: no implicit reference conversion error

Tags: c#, .net, generics, resharper

I tested this code and got that it doesn't compiles.

```
interface IE<T>
{

}

class A<T> : IE<T>
{
    public static void F<TU>() where TU : IE<T>
    {

    }

    static void Foo()
    {
        F<A<int>>();
    }
}
```

It fails even if I add `public static void F<TU>() where TU : A<int>, IE<T>`.

afaik it's valid according to C# specs. If I remove contraint `where TU : IE<T>` but in this case it couldn't affect, because `A<int>` is subtype of `IE<T>`.

And it's also funny because resharper suggest to add `IE<T>` interface to `A`[image]

why this code isn't valid?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's *not* valid. The constraint of

```
where TU : IE<T>
```

refers to the *current* `T`, i.e. the one for the type on which you're calling this method.

Consider a call of:

```
A<string>.Foo();
```

That's trying to pass `A<int>` as a type argument for `TU`, but the constraint means that there must be a reference conversion from `TU` to `IE<string>`, because `T` is `string`.

There's no conversion from `A<int>` to `IE<string>`, hence it's broken. Basically your expectation of "`A<int>` is subtype of `IE<T>`" isn't true for all `T`.

Now you could change it to:

```
public static void F<TU, TT>() where TU : IE<TT>
{
}

static void Foo()
{
    F<A<int>, int>();
}
```

*That's* now valid, because it doesn't involve `T` at all.